# Disable taskbar hotkey?

Tags: windows, hotkeys

On Windows 8 pressing "Windows + T" in any program moves keyboard focus to the taskbar.

I want to assign a different function to this hotkey, but the default is overriding my custom one. How can I disable the taskbar's hotkey?

Comment: What do you mean by "Custom one"?

Comment: @nixda I want to use that key combination inside a program that allows you to customize it's key bindings.

Comment: *"but the default is overriding my custom one"* that sounds like you already tried something and I just want to know what exactly

Comment: @nixda I setup a key binding for `windows + shift + t` within the program and when pressing it, the taskbar activates and the key press event never reaches the intended target (apparently the task bar key works with & without the shift key). I use multiple computers (the others are macs) and need to use the same key everywhere, since I have muscle memory for it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Disable specific hotkeys

Although undocumented, File Explorer (previously known as Windows Explorer) provides a per-user registry entry which can selectively disable some Explorer-related hotkeys. The registry value is called `DisabledHotkeys` and is located at:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

> Each character in the string data represents one key which is to be disabled in all its supported combinations. For instance, `F` disables both <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Interpretation is in terms of what programmers know as [virtual-key codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Alphabetical keys must be in upper case. For the <kbd>F1</kbd> key, use the lower-case `p`. For the <kbd>Break</kbd> key, the character must have the numerical value `0x13`.
>
> <sub>Source: [Disable Global Hot Keys](http://www.geoffchappell.com/notes/windows/shell/explorer/globalhotkeys.htm)</sub>

### Example

To disable <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> follow these steps:

1. Open a [command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-8).
2. Type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   ```
   reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "DisabledHotkeys" /t REG_SZ /d "T" /f
   ```
3. Log off and log back on to apply the changes.

### Remarks

- Works in Windows Vista and later. Only up to 22 characters of data are supported.
- According to my tests, by using this method you can't disable the following <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> shortcuts:

  - **Windows Vista**

    <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd>
  - **Windows 7**

    <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd>
  - **Windows 8.x**

    <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>

## References

- [Keyboard shortcuts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-8)
- [Disable Global Hot Keys](http://www.geoffchappell.com/notes/windows/shell/explorer/globalhotkeys.htm)
- [Virtual-Key Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: For reference, works to disable the default functionality of Win-1, Win-2, and so on, at least on WIndows 10.

Comment: Perfect, I could disable Win + 0-9 shortcuts.  Need to add that it's enough to kill "explorer" from task manager and run it again from task manager, then changes are applied without need to log-off.

Comment: A reboot may be required to apply changes

Comment: I have followed this process to remove the shortcut Win+V (used by Clipboard). All I had to do at the end was restart Windows Explorer. Now was able to assign that shortcut to a program of my choosing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to disable individual Windows-key hotkeys, but they can be disabled *en masse* by means of [a registry change](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-winx-shortcut-keys-on-windows-vista/), expressed here in [Microsoft's .reg file format](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516):

```
"Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoWinKeys"=dword:00000001
```

The change thus described may be made manually in Registry Editor, or by copying the above example to a file with extension ".reg" and run it; then, restart Windows Explorer via Task Manager (or just log out and back in) so that the change will take effect. To reverse the change, modify the file to contain `dword:00000000`, run it, and restart Explorer again. (At the linked site, you can download a zipfile containing pre-written .reg files for both options.)

If you want to retain some Windows-key hotkeys, while disabling others, your best option as far as I know is to disable them all using the above method, then use [AutoHotkey](http://l.autohotkey.net/) or some equivalent to create hotkey bindings for the actions you wish to retain.

Some such actions, such as invoking the Run dialog as <kbd>`Win`</kbd>-<kbd>`r`</kbd>, require Windows API calls to implement; [this site](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:IbzL_Hz1L4YJ:jpsoft.com/forums/threads/activating-the-run-dialog.4741/+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a) mentions a command-line method of invoking the Run dialog, thus:

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,#61
```

Similar methods will exist for other special actions; they may take some digging, but patience and perseverance will turn them up in the end.

**Update**: Even by this method, you may find it's not possible to override <kbd>`Win`</kbd>-<kbd>`l`</kbd>, the "lock screen" hotkey; it's been a couple years since I last messed with that, but if I recall correctly, that chord is trapped at a low enough level that even the user's Windows Explorer session never sees it, which would mean this method wouldn't affect it. Of course, I could misremember, so give it a try and see what happens.