# How can I disable the Ctrl+Alt+T hotkey owned by explorer.exe?

Tags: windows, hotkeys

I am annoyed by the global hotkey Ctrl+Alt+T, which focuses on the taskbar. According to hkexplr.exe the hotkey belongs to explorer.exe.

I tried the solution described in "[Disable taskbar hotkey?](https://superuser.com/questions/630112/disable-taskbar-hotkey)" (with a T instead of F), but that didn't work.

How can I disable this global hotkey so applications can use it?

Comment: I normally use something like autohotkey to do this.

Comment: How would that help me to disable a hotkey another application sets?

Comment: I was under the impression it was a windows hotkey, hence my suggestion, but it wouldn't help override a non-windows hotkey combination.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+Alt+T is not a [standard Windows hotkey](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-7).

You have some extension/utility program that's creating that shortcut.

Use `MSConfig` to disable all 3rd party start-ups and services and see if the hotkey still exists.  If not, then re-enable the 3rd-party start-ups and services one at a time until you find the culprit that's creating it.

Once you know, decide what to do from there (ie: disable the 3rd party process that's causing it, or use it's UI to configure a different key, if possible).