# Disabling Win+V on Windows

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for a long time with [PureText](https://stevemiller.net/puretext/).

**My Windows version is 1809 (OS Build 17763.439)**

Now all of a sudden windows has stolen the shortcut for its own clipboard history.
Window shows a popup proposing to enable its (presumably) new feature - Clipboard History.

How do I disable it do get [PureText](https://stevemiller.net/puretext/) working again?

Comment: What do you claim that Win+V does exactly

Comment: Window shows a popup proposing to enable its (presumably) new feature - Clipboard History.

Comment: You should update your question to indicate the version of Windows 10 you are using and what the shortcut currently does for you.  What version of Windows 10 you are using is vital information since, Clipboard History, is indeed a new feature that was only recently added with the release of Windows 10 version 1809.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/725556/2761).

Basically create a registry key named `DisabledHotkeys` in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced` and specify the list of letter keys whose combinations with the Win key you'd like to disable, just "V" in this case.

It did work for <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> but didn't work for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> when I specified "VQ".

An explorer process restart or reboot my be necessary to apply the changes.

Comment: A reboot may be required to apply changes

Comment: `reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v DisabledHotkeys /t REG_SZ /d V`

Comment: Just restarting explorer process is enough for me, no reboot required.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. The registry hacks didn't work. I upgraded my PureText app from v3.0 to the latest v6.2. It now has an "Experimental" mode under Advanced options that manages the <kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> clipboard pop up. Seems to be working fine for me so far!

[image: [PureText experimental advanced options]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3OPn.jpg)

Comment: I had to restart to get this to 'take'. Awesome fix: thanks!!

Comment: This is the one solution that worked perfectly for me, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Registry Key specifically to disable this feature.

1. Open Regedit
2. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Clipboard`
3. Set `IsCloudAndHistoryFeatureAvailable` to `0`.
   If this key isn't there, create a DWORD with the name `IsCloudAndHistoryFeatureAvailable` and set it to 0.

This also removes the clipboard menu from Windows Settings which only contains settings for this feature.

Comment: You have to restart explorer.exe or reboot for the Win+V popup to stop appearing. `Start > Settings > System > Clipboard` disappears when a new Settings window is opened, which confused me.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft's documentation of Windows Keyboard Shortcuts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445), this can be turned off by selecting Start  > Settings  > System  > Clipboard, and turn off the toggle under Clipboard history.

Comment: It IS set to Off in the settings, but it would show a prompt to turn it on when I press Win+V.

Comment: It's rather short-sighted of Microsoft not to skip capturing the activation keystroke when you have disabled the feature.