# Can I turn off clipboard history completely?

Tags: windows, clipboard

Is there a way to completely turn off clipboard history on Windows 10?

I know there's a "clipboard history" toggle in settings, but that doesn't stop the "clipboard smiley" dialog to come up when I press Win-V.

That Win-V shortcut conflicts with another application I use and I don't want both dialogs showing up every time I press Win-V.

Comment: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/109799-turn-off-clipboard-history-windows-10-a.html

Comment: @Moab - That is the toggle setting that I said I already knew about. It does NOT prevent the dialog from coming up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1439819/disabling-winv-on-windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling Win+V on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1439819/disabling-winv-on-windows)

Comment: Not quite. Version 6.2 does stop the "clipboard smiley" from popping up, but now it opens up the Windows Start Menu (as if I had pressed the Windows key by itself). EDIT: After some experimentation I found out that it does work correctly if I hold the windows key a little bit longer after releasing V. If I go too fast, that's when I get the Start Menu. I can live with that. Thanks for the heads up!