# Windows 10 Clipboard history and feature completely gone

Tags: windows, windows-10

A few days ago, out of nowhere, my ability to use Win+V disappeared. The clipboard settings option in System -> Clipboard is also gone. I tried to restore before that point, but my System gets stuck on a file it can't restore. What can I do?

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0rsy.png)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3OPn.jpg

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1439819/disabling-winv-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two errors:  Clipboard and Settings. There may be other errors as well.

**(A) So first run a Windows 10 Repair Install.**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

Note:  You can either Run the ISO in place or download it and run setup.exe on the USB where the ISO file was downloaded.

The first option is Keep Everything.

That may or may not work, and also Keep Everything (or Keep Data) does not repair a damaged Windows User Profile.

Do try the Keep Everything option first.

**(B) If it does not work, back up and reinstall Windows 10.**

Because of the multiple errors, back up and reinstall is most likely your course of action.

Comment: The download button is used to create the ISO on a USB or drive right? Do I run the ISO on startup or what do I do?

Comment: Mount the ISO within windows then launch setup.exe

Comment: Yes you can do as @ramhound says.  I have also just clicked on Open at the download step and run in place. I made the appropriate note in my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Clipboard History may be provided by ClipboardServer.dll which is part of TextInputHost.exe.

TextInputHost.exe comes from the Windows App `MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS`

Try reinstalling `MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS` using these steps:

1. Open PowerShell as an Administrator.
2. Run this command:

`Add-AppxPackage -ForceApplicationShutdown -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$((Get-AppxPackage MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS).InstallLocation)\AppxManifest.xml"`

3. Restart Windows.

That command does the following:

- Grabs details of Client.CBS using `Get-AppxPackage MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS`
- Specifically grabs the InstallLocation (Which leads to `C:\Windows\SystemApps\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy` on my PC.
- Appends `\AppxManifest.xml` to this path which is a file containing information Windows needs to install an app.
- Runs `Add-AppxPackage` using th AppxManifest.xml to reinstall the app.
- `-ForceApplicationShutdown` will make it close the app so it can be reinstalled first.
- `-DisableDevelopmentMode` changes the behaviour to allow Apps to be reinstalled.

If that doesnt' work, check that it's not disabled in the Registry.

1. Run `regedit` from the start menu.
2. Navigate to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Clipboard`
3. There should be a value called `IsCloudAndHistoryFeatureAvailable` set it to 1. If that value isn't present right-click > new > DWORD. Enter the name as `IsCloudAndHistoryFeatureAvailable` and set it's value to 1.
4. Restart your PC.

Comment: I attempted this and it did not work after a restart.

Comment: @Gmanc2 thanks for trying it, I've added a second section for changing a registry key, please try it.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's unlikely anything except a recent [full disk image](https://www.pcwdld.com/best-disk-imaging-software) could restore items in clipboard history; [Windows *Restore*](https://www.customguide.com/windows-10/system-restore) only fixes System files and Registry. If you haven't made a recent disk image, the history is history.
2. To get *Clipboard History* working again, first try fixing files using [DISM and SFC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e). If that doesn't work, reinstall [Windows 10 from ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/).
3. Because of limitations and changes made to the Windows *Clipboard History*, there are numerous free third-party replacements. Try [CopyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/) and its [many alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/copyq/), instead of fixing the Windows 10 issue.

However, there have been