# How to disable Ctrl+T taskbar hide hotkey?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, office365, group-policy, hotkeys, regedit

On Windows 11 I want to disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> hotkey that hides/shows the taskbar so that it can be used to open new browser tabs instead. It seems to be [a problem with PowerPoint](https://reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/vjvi14/ctrlt_to_open_new_tab_not_working/ido4nid/); I am currently running the latest versions of PowerPoint 365 and Edge, but I have had this issue before with [PowerPoint 2016/Firefox 101](https://reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/vjvi14/ctrlt_to_open_new_tab_not_working/).

According to [a previous Superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/630112/disable-taskbar-hotkey/725556#725556), it is possible to disable some <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+[key] hotkeys, but I can't figure out how to do that for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: Ctrl+T does nothing special on my Windows 11. Try to boot in Safe mode - if the problem disappears then some installed product is using this shortcut key.

Comment: @harrymc No issues with PowerPoint?

Comment: For PowerPoint, Ctrl+T brings up the font dialog on the selected element. That's its function - it does nothing to the taskbar.

Comment: On my recently upgraded Windows 11, if I am in Google Chrome, CTRL-T opens a new tab; if Chrome is minimised, it opens an Explorer window at This P

Comment: Windows 11 23H2 here and same as harrymc  - Ctrl-T does do anything.